# Code duplication in a shell script

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script

My bash script (lets call it `myscript`) takes input either from stdin (pipe), or form a regular file (if filename was provided as an argument)

```
a) someprog | myscript

   or

b) myscript file.txt
```

Then, the data is processed line by line. At the moment, my code looks something like the following:

```
if [ -t 0 ] ; then
    while read LINE
      do
         prog_1
         prog_2
         ...
         prog_n
      done
else
    while read LINE
      do
         prog_1
         prog_2
         ...
         prog_n
      done < $1
fi
```

This script works fine, but there seems to be too much duplicity. I am wondering whether there is a better (more elegant) way to do it. All the steps `1` to `n` are the same. The only difference is whether there is a `< $1` at the end or not. is there no better way to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Functions are the general way to reduce code duplication. This case isn't any different. You just need to to define a function to implement your `while read` logic.

```
myfunc() {
    while read LINE
    do
        prog_1
        prog_2
        ...
        prog_n
    done
}

if [[ -t 0 ]]; then
    myfunc # read stdin passed to the script
else
    myfunc < "$1" # redirect file to stdin
fi
```

Answer (score 2):

I usually use

```
cat "$@" | while read line ; do
    ...
done
```

The only problem might be if someone calls `someprog | myscript file.txt` (but the same problem exists in the original code).

Answer (score 1):

If an argument is given, redirect stdin from it then reuse the code.

```
if [ -t 0 ]; then
    exec 3<&0
elif (( $# > 0 )) && [[ -r $1 ]]; then
    exec 3<"$1"
else
    echo no stdin and no file to read
    exit 1
fi

while IFS= read -r -u 3 LINE; do
     prog_1
     prog_2
     ...
     prog_n
done

exec 3<&-
```